# Android SimpleCursorAdapter - Limiting ListView results

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I apologize in advance as I am away from my laptop and cannot produce any code examples, but hopefully I can be clear enough to have my question answered.  I have a ListView backed by a sqlite db (via a SimpleCursorAdapter).  I am trying to implement functionality so the list only shows a certain # of elements from the db query at a time.  I've done this by loading all data from the db in onCreate, and overriding the getCount method of SimpleCursorAdapter with the preferred # of elements when the list is initiated.  I also have a button that loads more elements to the list.  This is done by updating the count that getCount should return.

This works fine in adding more listview rows, however I'm seeing strange behavior with the contents in my list after I click the button.  I'm seeing duplicate list elements and incorrect element contents, which are set in my bindview method.  I'm assuming this had something to do with overriding the getCount method (i'm sure thee's a better way to do a "Load Next 25" function), as I am not seeing this behavior when I just show the whole db result set and don't override that method.

I guess my question is can overriding the getCount method result in funny behavior  in the bindview method when you're dealing with a SimpleCursorAdapter?  What's the best way to implement this type of functionality with db query results backing your ListView?

Thanks in advance...if needed I can provide code snippets tomorrow when I'm back at my laptop.

Comment: I don't recommend that. What happens if the DB contains less than # entries? I would guess this can lead to unpredictable behaviour. I would go with the solution of Flo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can archive this by simply using a different query to get you results. SQLite supports a [LIMIT operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) which can returns the top n results of a query.

So your first query looks something like this: `SELECT [your columns] FROM [your table] LIMIT 25`

And when the button that loads the next 25 results is pressed, you create a new query with a limit of 50 and bind the resulting cursor to the SimpleCursorAdapter using the [changeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29)() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  I was trying to work in the confines of the db.query() call which I don't think allows a LIMIT parameter, but I neglected to consider just using the execSQL() method with a straight SQL statement.  I will make this change in my code, thanks again!  One quick follow up question...if I use this approach, will the ListView start back from the cursor's first results?  In other words, will the ListView scroll back up to the top automatically, or will it keep the user near where the ListView left off and the "Next x" button was pressed to see the new records brought in.

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your second question, I don't know how the list will react, but I'm sure there's a way that you let the list scroll down to the last item before the new query. Although I never used them before the methods setSelection() and setSelectionAfterHeaderView() of the ListView class look very promising for this issue.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at those methods.  Thanks.

Comment: This solution is really good and works for when we are going down the list.  Can anyone recommend logic where from the Adapter we can load the previous rows to go back.